# Calling a function “Double.foo()” in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin

I am new to programming and Kotlin. I ran across a Kotlin function that I would like to incorporate in my studies but I can not figure out how to call it. I found this function in one of the answers to a question on "Rounding a Double to two decimal places in Kotlin."

This was the answer:

```
fun Double.roundTo2DecimalPlaces() =
   BigDecimal(this).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toDouble()
```

The problem is I do not know how to call this function.

Could someone please give me an example of how I would call this function?

Thanks

Clan

Answer (score 4):

This is an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) on `Double`, so you call it directly on any `Double` you have defined.

> Kotlin, similar to C# and Gosu, provides the ability to extend a class with new functionality without having to inherit from the class or use any type of design pattern such as Decorator. This is done via special declarations called extensions.

To call this specific example, define a `Double` and call your function directly on it.

```
val d1: Double = 3.141
println(d1.roundTo2DecimalPlaces()) // prints "3.14"
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like that:

```
(123.112363).roundTo2DecimalPlaces()
```

This function is a type of "extension functions" which is handled by the compiler as if it was a method. (But in reality it is a static function).
So call it from Kotlin like it is a method.

Comment: I appreciate you said that an extension function is actually a static method, since it is totally fine to call it on a `null` object (provided that the receiver of that extension function is nullable)

Answer (score 1):

As a Java programmer you might be used to static utility functions like this one:

```
public static double roundTo2DecimalPlaces(double d)
```

This is basically what Kotlin tries to eliminate by providing the functionality of [**extension function**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) like the one you’re asking about. It can be invoked on a **receiver** of type `Double` like this:

```
(10.0).roundTo2DecimalPlaces()
```

And of course on corresponding variables:

```
val d = 10.0
d.roundTo2DecimalPlaces()
```